# Cosa significa "piantare le persone su due piedi"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Il padre si era opposto che lei andasse a servizio: gli pareva una cosa contraria ai 
>   suoi principi. «Mia figlia non deve far la serva a nessuno» diceva. E anche quando Mara era tornata a casa per Natale, aveva insistito perchè non ripartisse. «Sì, e gli lascio tutta la mia roba» ribatté Mara. «Che c'entra: la roba, ci vado io a riprenderla.» «Ma non si può **piantare una famiglia così su due piedi**.»

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "piantare una famiglia così su due piedi" nel brano precedente. Si tratta di un modo di dire? L'ho cercato nel Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovato. Mi potreste spiegare qual è il suo significato?

Comment: ***Su due piedi***:

(loc.avv.), senza indugio, immediatamente, all’improvviso: così su due piedi non saprei rispondere. De Mauro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Su due piedi* significa "all'improvviso, immediatamente", mentre *piantare* significa "lasciare, abbandonare" (di solito, si usa quando un uomo o una donna interrompono una relazione sentimentale). La frase significa che Mara non può interrompere il lavoro presso quella famiglia all'improvviso, senza avvisare per tempo, semplicemente non tornando lì come invece vorrebbe suo padre.